# Two seperate count in one SOQL query

Tags: soql

I am using below queries to get two different count

```
Integer countActive = [SELECT Count() from Account where Status__c = 'Active' And ProviderId__c LIKE '%00%'];
Integer countInactive = [SELECT Count() from Account where Status__c = 'Inactive' And ProviderId__c LIKE '%00%'];
```

Is there a way to get the count in single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have this using a single query using group by and the aggregateresult as below

```
list<aggregateresult> agr = [select count(id), status  from account where ProviderId__c LIKE '%00%' group by status ];
integer active =  (integer)(agr[0].get('Status') == 'Active'? agr[0].get('expr0') : agr[1].get('expr0'));
integer inactive = (integer)(agr[0].get('Status') == 'Inactive'? agr[0].get('expr0') : agr[1].get('expr0'));
system.debug('Active '+active);
system.debug('Inactive '+inactive);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can not do same with two criteria in single query. The best and optimized way to achieve this:

```
list<account> lstAcc = new list<account>([SELECT Status__c from Account where ProviderId__c LIKE '%00%' order by Status__c]);
integer ActiveCount = 0;
for(account objAcc:lstAcc){
    if(objAcc.Status__c== 'Active'){
        ActiveCount++;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
Integer InActiveCount = lstAcc.size()-ActiveCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a query with Group by clause.

```
List<AggregateResult> results = [SELECT Count(Id), Status__c FROM Account WHERE ProviderId__c LIKE '%00%' GROUP BY Status__c]
```

and then get the active and inactive status values.